# How can I make and query read only snapshots in Postgres (or MySql)?

Tags: postgresql, snapshot

I'd like to create a read-only snapshot of a database at the end of each day, and keep them around for a couple of months.

I'd then like to be able to run queries against a specific (named) snapshot.

Is this possible to achieve elegantly and with minimal resource usage (the database only changes very slowly, but has a few GBs of data - so almost all data is common to all snapshots).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way to create a snapshot in PostgreSQL is to use pg_dump/pg_restore.

A much quicker method is to simply use CREATE DATABASE to clone your database.

```
CREATE DATABASE my_copy_db TEMPLATE my_production_db;
```

which will be much faster than a dump/restore. The only drawback to this solution is that the source database must not have any open connections.

The copy will not be read-only by default, but you could simply revoke the respective privileges from the users to ensure that

Comment: I was hoping that there might be an elegant way, i.e. avoiding copying shared data.  I've probably been too spoilt by immutable data structures in Haskell and Clojure.

Comment: @chrisdew: doing snapshots like that (without actually copying the data) is probably better done on filesystem level. I think there are filesystems which can do things like that, but I have no experience with that.